# merge several lists but keep only values that are found on all the list

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If I have the arrays:

```
var list1 = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5};
var list2 = new int[] { 1,2,3};
var list3 = new int[] { 2,3};
```

what method can help me keep only value found on all the lists. In this example I will like to end up with `{2,3}` because those two values are found on all the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method to get the intersection of any number of sequences:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    if (!sequences.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    var set = new HashSet<T>(sequences.First());
    foreach (var sequence in sequences.Skip(1))
    {
        set.IntersectWith(sequence);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Note that unlike repeated calls to the LINQ `Intersect` method, this won't be repeatedly rebuilding an intermediate `HashSet`.  It'll re-use the same one throughout.

Comment: Nice solution! Although I'm not sure if it matters that a hashset has no particular order and doesn't allow duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Intersect` -> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

```
var list = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3);
```

Comment: that will return `{1,2,3,4,5}`  I only want {2,3} because those are the only two items that are contained on all the lists.

Comment: @TonoNam: No; this will return what you're looking for.  (tested)

Comment: Oh I treid your example with the word Union instead of Intersect. Thanks for the help it works great!

Comment: @TonoNam That was an error on my part. I've since updated. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I did not remember about the Intersect keyword. +1 thanks it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Intersect method that's a part of LINQ like this:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3);
```

If you want a method that you can pass an arbitrary number of lists you can use this:

```
public static int[] Process(params int[][] values)
{
    int[] result = values[0];

    foreach (int[] value in values)
    {
        result = result.Intersect(value).ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var result = Process(list1, list2, list3);
```

Comment: Your variable method is highly inefficient, given that you're not only constantly needlessly materializing the sub-intersections into arrays, but you're not able to utilize the same intermediate `HashSet` between intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Other has already proposed good and working solutions. Based on their answer I propose this one:

```
 public static class IEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> one, params IEnumerable<T>[] others)
        {
            var result = one;
            foreach (var other in others)
                result = result.Intersect(other);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And the usage will be like this:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2,list3,...continued to...listn);
```